# Why google took HTML Select option for description?

Tags: meta-tags, google-search, googlebot

If I search for our website www.captaincookresorts.com on google, first result has correct title corresponding homepage title, but description below is total nonsense.

[Screenshot here](http://postimg.org/image/8iyxzxl77/)

It's part of one language select's option. There are all informations like meta description, keywords, schema.org tags ..., but google chose this.
Can anybody enlighten me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `option` elements look like:

```html
<option value="it">&lt;span class=&quot;lang-row sys-disablePropragation&quot; rel=&quot;http://it.captaincookresorts.com&quot; onclick=&quot;window.location=jQuery(this).attr(&#39;rel&#39;);&quot; title=&quot;Italiano&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;langcode&quot;&gt;IT&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;ico-flag flag-it&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</option>
```

Instead, you probably want something like:

```html
<option value="it">Italiano</option>
```

The *content model* of [`option` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/forms.html#the-option-element) is "[Text](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/dom.html#text-content)", so they can’t contain HTML/JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I know there's HTML and JS, it used to generate "nicer" select, but I don't understand why google chose this part of page content. I thought it searches for meaningful text parts, not HTML gibbrish. It decreases a little bit my beleive in google AI.

Comment: @user3219948: It looks like you searched for your URL/domain. And the matching text for your search query is contained in the `option` (`rel=&quot;http://it.captaincookresorts.com&quot;`).

Comment: Yaeh, I see now. Search results shows result description according my search query. Didn't noticed that before. Thanx.